How to list COM over USB ports in Powershell?
I'm trying to list COM over USB ports in Powershell.
So far, I found this command on the internet :
PS C:\> Get-CimInstance Win32_SerialPort | Select Name, Description, DeviceID

Name                                               Description                                 DeviceID
----                                               -----------                                 --------
Standard Serial over Bluetooth link (COM4)         Standard Serial over Bluetooth link         COM4
Standard Serial over Bluetooth link (COM5)         Standard Serial over Bluetooth link         COM5
Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL (COM3) Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL COM3


PS C:\>

But it does not show me any USB COM ports.

You can list serial ports in PowerShell as follows:
[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::GetPortNames()

You can also interact with them in a similar style. Below reads a line from the port, for example:
function Read-SerialPort {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$PortName,
        [int]$BaudRate = 9600,
        [System.IO.Ports.Parity]$Parity = [System.IO.Ports.Parity]::None,
        [int]$DataBits = 8,
        [System.IO.Ports.StopBits]$StopBits = [System.IO.Ports.StopBits]::One
    )

    try {
        $port = [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::new($PortName, $BaudRate, $Parity, $DataBits, $StopBits)
        $port.Open()
        $data = $port.ReadLine()
        return $data
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Error reading from port: $_"
    }
    finally {
        if ($port -and $port.IsOpen) {
            $port.Close()
            $port.Dispose()
        }
    }
}

Read-SerialPort -PortName COM5


I found this command :
gwmi Win32_PNPEntity | ? ClassGuid -eq '{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}' | % Name

thanks to this answer.
